# Styling Navbar Links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I know similar questions have been asked, however after a lot of solution searching, none of them are working for me.

I am attempting to style (mostly concerned with font, color, and hover) the links in my Navbar.

html:

```
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">FLO Home</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-links" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#services">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</nav>
```

css:

```
.navbar {
background-color: white;
}

.nav-links li a {
color: black;
}
```

What it looks like: 
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi23Q.png)

Comment: Was there an actual question you had?

Comment: yeah, how to change the color of the navbar links... as you can see, the css styles them to be black, however they are not black, as shown in the screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap, to color the ANCHOR links:

```
.nav a {
  color: black;
}
```

You can also use Dev-Tools in the browser and right-click on the element you want to style, so it identifies the classes.

Comment: Change it to `.nav > a` and none of that is bootstrap specific.

Comment: Still didn't change it, iv'e tried both **.nav a { color:black; }** and **.nav > a { color:black; }**

Comment: Then you have something else messing with inheritance somewhere.

Comment: I have in the <head> section... <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

Comment: what happens when you click on the element in Dev-Tools?  It should tell you exactly what your CSS tags need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class in the a elements you got in the nav bar. Name it something like blackletter for example.  Then in css put color:black under .blackletter

Comment: have tried that :/ In the html I created a new class called "nav-links" and added it to the div containing the and then in the list. In the css I put "nav-links a { color: black; }